# Using lodash isEqual() to compare single object property with matching properties from large array with multiple objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, object, lodash

I've looked at [lodash documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEqual) and played around with comparing simple objects.  I've also found a number of explanations online for comparing entire objects and other types of comparisons, but I want to compare one property value in a single object with the values of *all* properties of a certain name in a large array with multiple objects.

Is lodash smart enough to do this as is, and, if so, what would be the proper syntax to handle this?  Or do I need some sort of loop to work through the larger object and recursively compare its properties of a certain name with the small object property?

The javascript comparison I'm looking for would be something like this, but I don't know how to indicate that I want to compare ***all*** `itemURL` properties in the large array:

```
// guard clause to end the larger function if test is true, any match found
if (_.isEqual(feedItem.link, rssDataFileArr.itemURL)) {
    return; 
}
```

Small object example:

```
const feedItem = {
  link: 'https://news.google.com/rss/search?q=nodejs',
  otherProperty: 'whatever'
}
```

Large array of objects example:

```
const rssDataFileArr = [
  {
    "itemURL": "https://news.google.com/rss/search?q=rss-parser",
    "irrelevantProperty": "hello"
  },
  {
    "itemURL": "https://news.google.com/rss/search?q=nodejs",
    "irrelevantProperty": "world"
  },
  {
    "itemURL": "https://news.google.com/rss/search?q=javascript",
    "irrelevantProperty": "hello"
  }
]
```

Any and all help appreciated.

Comment: If I were you, I would use built-in [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method.

Answer (score 0):

As per suggestion in comment, I went with a built-in javascript method instead of lodash.  I used `some()` because I only needed a true/false boolean result, not a `find()` value.

```
const feedItem = {
  link: 'https://news.google.com/rss/search?q=nodejs',
  otherProperty: 'whatever',
};
const rssDataFileArr = [
  {
    itemURL: 'https://news.google.com/rss/search?q=rss-parser',
    irrelevantProperty: 'hello',
  },
  {
    itemURL: 'https://news.google.com/rss/search?q=nodejs',
    irrelevantProperty: 'world',
  },
  {
    itemURL: 'https://news.google.com/rss/search?q=javascript',
    irrelevantProperty: 'hello',
  },
  {
    itemURL: 'https://news.google.com/rss/search?q=nodejs',
    irrelevantProperty: 'world',
  },
];
const linkMatch = rssDataFileArr.some(
  ({ itemURL }) => itemURL === feedItem.link
);
// guard clause to end the larger function if test is true, any match found
if (linkMatch) {
  console.log('linkMatch is true');
  return;
}
```